# Одна переменная, несколько значений. Вывести все со знаком разделителя. PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вставить знак разделителя между значениями?

Есть код

```
$cur_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'person_status' );
if (is_array($cur_terms) || is_object($cur_terms))
{
  foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){
    echo $cur_term->name;
```

Выводятся все значения, как и надо. НО выводятся так

> Значение1Значение2

А надо вот так

> Значение1, Значение2

Comment: вместо echo сделайте `$result .= "$name, "`  и потом `echo trim($name, ", ")`

Comment: либо `echo ($idx == 0 ? "": ", ") . $name`

Comment: не знаю, тогда уж лучше временный массив и implode, не?

Comment: @splash58 да вы зря ответ удалили, надо было просто сделать `(array)$cur_terms`

Comment: Теоретически да, но я бы глянул на этот объект, хотя, судя по foreach...